# Difference between parentheses and braces in terminal?

Tags: shell

```
( du /etc; du /var; ) > tmp.txt

{ du /etc; du /var; } > tmp.txt
```

Is there a difference between the () and {}?

The output of tmp.txt seems exactly the same, and I was wondering whether i'm missing something here.

Comment: See [Grouping Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) under _2.9.4 Compound Commands_

Comment: try inserting `exit ;` between the du.

Comment: [This is the closest answer](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/153286-using-braces-bash-behaviour.html) I found in the web. The exact issue has not been explained in this site.

Comment: Both of them are [Grouping Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01), but `{ list; }` executes commands in current shell environment.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Parentheses cause the commands to be run in a subshell.

Braces cause the commands to be grouped together but not in a subshell.

Given that your example does not use side-effects, there is no real difference between both. If there were side-effects, e.g. setting or modifying shell variables, there is a difference as such side-effects applied to a sub-shell will be forgotten when this sub-shell ends.

To understand the "side-effect", see the following examples:

**Using parentheses `()`:**

```bash
v="test"; 
( echo $v; v="modified"; echo $v; ); 
echo $v;

# output:
#   test
#   modified
#   test
```

**Using curly braces `{}`:**

```bash
v="test"; 
{ echo $v; v="modified"; echo $v; }; 
echo $v;

# output:
#   test
#   modified
#   modified
```

If you however take a closer look and compare the behavior of different shell implementations, it becomes confusing:

The Bourne Shell e.g. runs grouped commands in a subshell in case there is an I/O redirection and ksh93 avoids subshells by implementing virtual subshell behavior that is done by creating a temporary copy of new parameters. Whether this is always 100% correct is not known, `ksh93 Version M 1993-12-28 s+` from 2009 e.g. implements $(...) incorrectly and $(alias a=b) affects the main shell.

So in general: if you are interested in specific aspects, be careful and check your shell for it's actual behavior.

Comment: (I wouldn't have bothered mentioning it but since you're maintaining a Bourne shell ;)), _...not in a subshell_, except for the Bourne shell that runs compound commands in subshells when redirected.

Comment: Well parentheses grant the commands to be in a subshell, with braces, it still may happen ;-) but ksh93 does not even create a real subshell for parentheses, but rather emulates the effects of a subshell by using a temporary new copy of parameters.

Comment: Yes, you'll notice that the POSIX spec is careful to talk only of _subshell environment_ with no implication that it may involve a child process. And with many shells that implement subshells using a child process, `(a;b)` will not spawn more processes than `{a;b;}` (if `b` is not a builtin nor function nor compound command and there's no local trap) as `b` will be executed in that child subshell process.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the only difference is that: parentheses use a subshell and braces don't?

And the output stays the same, regardless of the subshell (in this case).

Thankyou, this helped!

Comment: See my new paragraph about side-effects. In your example, there is no visible difference.