# how to nest conditional script operators -a -o in an if statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, test

If i want to combine the -a and -o script operators in an if statement, how could I do that? For example:

```bsh
if [ ( -e file.txt -a -r file.txt ) -o ( -e file2.txt -a -r file2.txt ) ]; then .... fi
```

Can I accomplish something like this? Right now I'm getting an error when I try to run this.

Comment: In general, instead of writing "_I'm getting an error_" please don't leave use guessing but state clearly and completely what the error message is. Same thing for "_when I try to run this_" please show us exactly how you run it

Comment: In this particular case, you could just drop the `-e` tests, since `-r` includes the test for existence. So just `if [ -r file.txt ] && [ -r file2.txt ]; then ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double brackets (see [Why does parameter expansion with spaces without quotes work inside double brackets "[[" but not inside single brackets "["?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/why-does-parameter-expansion-with-spaces-without-quotes-work-inside-double-brack)). Use the `&&` and `||` double-bracket condition operators instead of the `-a` and `-o` test/single-bracket condition operators. This works in bash, also in ksh and zsh, but not in plain sh.

```
if [[ ( -e file.txt && -r file.txt ) || ( -e file2.txt && -r file2.txt ) ]]; then
```

Alternatively, with single brackets, use `[` around single checks, use the `&&` and `||` shell operators outside of brackets instead of using the `-a` and `-o` test operators inside brackets, and use `{ … }` for grouping (see [Difference between parentheses and braces in terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267660/difference-between-parentheses-and-braces-in-terminal)). This works in any sh-style shell.

```
if { [ -e file.txt ] && [ -r file.txt ]; } ||
   { [ -e file2.txt ] && [ -r file2.txt ]; }
then …
```

Alternatively, you can use `\(` and `\)` (or any other way of quoting the parentheses) inside single brackets (again, see [Why does parameter expansion with spaces without quotes work inside double brackets "[[" but not inside single brackets "["?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32210/why-does-parameter-expansion-with-spaces-without-quotes-work-inside-double-brack) for an explanation). However this can cause the condition to be parsed incorrectly if a file name looks like a test operator (`(`, `=`, `-e`, …).

Comment: @zevzek For example, if the first `file.txt` is `)` and the second `file.txt` is `=`, the first half of the command is `[ \( -e \) -a -r = \) ` and that leads to a syntax error. I think with a little more work you can find an example that is accepted but parsed in an unintended way.

Comment: @zevzek I took `( -e file.txt -a -r file.txt )` and replaced the file names by `)` and `=` respectively. The closing parenthesis that was intended to be recognized as one is present. Yes, it's a syntax error. That's the point.

Comment: @zevzek What statement are you talking about? The general wisdom around `[ … ]` is not to use it with compound conditions to avoid the risk of unintended parses: only use a single operator, don't use `-a` or `-o`. This isn't specifically about parentheses.